# Select users who fits in timetable mysql

Tags: mysql, select, timetable

I need to select all users who "fits" in theirs working timetables.

Table in MySQL
**Timetable:**

```
user_id                           PRIMARY
day_number(0-sunday 6-saturday)   PRIMARY (one user - one day)
start                             start worktime 
end                               end worktime
```

Sample user:

```
user_id    = 1
day_number = 1
start      = 10:00
end        = 18:00

user_id    = 1
day_number = 2
start      = 12:00
end        = 18:00

user_id    = 1
day_number = 3
start      = 14:00
end        = 16:00
```

Now I want select every user who works **from 1(Monday) to 3(Wednesday) from 14:00 to 16:00**.
Sample user (with id 1) should be included.

Any Ideas?

Comment: What is column type for Start and End column

Comment: Start and End is Time type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id
FROM   my_table
  NATURAL JOIN (SELECT 1 day_number UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) days
  JOIN (SELECT MAKETIME(14,0,0) start, MAKETIME(16,0,0) end) times
    ON my_table.start <= times.start
   AND my_table.end   >= times.end
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT my_table.day_number) = 3 -- number of days in range
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31660/2/0).

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `Timetable` 
WHERE day_number between 
 1 and 3 
AND TIME_TO_SEC( start ) <= TIME_TO_SEC(  '14:00' ) 
AND TIME_TO_SEC( end ) >= TIME_TO_SEC(  '16:00' )
```

Or

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `Timetable` 
WHERE day_number in (1,2,3 )
AND TIME_TO_SEC( start ) <= TIME_TO_SEC(  '14:00' ) 
AND TIME_TO_SEC( end ) >= TIME_TO_SEC(  '16:00' )
```

Comment: This wont work if the user has only two days (1,2) in DB. Script shoudnt select him but in this case it does. Problem is in `day_number in (1,2,3)`

Answer (score 0):

**Try the code below:**

```
Select * from Timetable
Where day_number>=1 and day_number <=3 And
hour(start) >= 12 and hour(end)<= 16
```